# How to generate a series of growing values and timestamps for cell that updates automatically?

Tags: microsoft-excel-2007, vba

I have a cell A1 which references a sheet that gets updated by an external source (database). My goal is to record a log that traces the growing value of cell A1 at each different time the data is refreshed.

I found multiple resources on creating timestamps, but was not able to find one where I could have multiple timestamps for the same value.

The outcome should appear like:

- May 9th, USD 50
- May 10th, USD 80
- May 11th, USD 80

I guess the key is to always create a new row each time the cell is refreshed, but I don't know how to do it :)

Answer (score 0):

I think you are actually nearly there but your terminology has tripped you up.

With a spreadsheet you are not really "creating" new rows, simply moving to ones that are already provided to you.

You can do this one of two ways. Assuming you are using VBA. Either just issue a move down command to move the active cell.

Somewhat more robust though is keep track of the "current" row. When you update the sheet, also increment the current row number ready for the next update. Then use that number as the row reference to update the cell.